# How to login google API in Xenforo 2 with limit domain (Organization domain)

Tags: google-oauth

I want to my web (that using Xenforo ver 2) login google API with Organization domain

example : only accept email with domain "user1@mydomain.com"
if other domain login with reject.

Comment: add-on name to [Datio] Allowed Emails . solve my problem.

https://xenforo.com/community/threads/allowedemails.140167/

Answer (score 0):

To whitelist email domains you can use this addon
https://xenforo.com/community/threads/allowedemails.140167/